# Return Future within Future's then

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have this two shared preferences

```
<string name="flutter.39281a04d2b8c8ba">{"name":"student","id":"UmWq","token":"LVF-M","isIncoming":true,"uuid":"39281a04d2b8c8ba"}</string>

<string name="flutter.4c434612edcff4bc">{"name":"student","id":"ozjU","token":"GXUTR","isIncoming":true,"uuid":"4c434612edcff4bc"}</string>
```

I have an id, and from this `id` I want to retreive the `uuid` in order to create a file:

```
MySharedPreferences.getUuid(id).then((uuid) {
   print("ended up with this uuid: $uuid");
   FileManager.createFile(uuid, form.title).then((file) => {
       file.writeAsString(str)
   });
});
```

This is the `getUuid` method:

```
static Future<String> getUuid(String id) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    for (String key in prefs.getKeys()){
      print("looking at $key");
      if (!key.contains("#")){
        return getData(key).then((value){
          print("got this value: $value");
          Map<String, dynamic> endpointJson = jsonDecode(value);
          EndpointData endpoint = EndpointData.fromJson(endpointJson);
          print("endpoint.id: ${endpoint.id}");
          print("id: $id");
          if (endpoint.id == id){
            print("the good return");
            return endpoint.uuid;
          }
          return null;
        });
      }else{
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, `getUuid`, retrieves a list of all keys inside shared preferences and iterates over them. For each key, I read the data associated and check if the `id` matches mine, therefore returning `uuid`.

Now, I know the problem, but I can't find a way to fix it. The problem is as follows. Presuming my `id` is `ozjU`, my `getUuid` function iterates the keys in order, so if first checks `39281a04d2b8c8ba`. `39281a04d2b8c8ba`'s id is not equal to mine, so inside `getData` returns null, which makes `getUuid` return null too. I don't know how to make `getData` return a value if `endpoint.id == id` or not return anything and let the outer `for` keep iterating over the remaining keys.

EDIT: As requested, tested as following and still uuid is null:

```
static Future<String> getUuid(String id) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    for (String key in prefs.getKeys()){
      print("looking at $key");
      if (!key.contains("#")){
        return getData(key).then((value){
          print("got this value: $value");
          Map<String, dynamic> endpointJson = jsonDecode(value);
          EndpointData endpoint = EndpointData.fromJson(endpointJson);
          print("endpoint.id: ${endpoint.id}");
          print("id: $id");
          if (endpoint.id == id){
            print("the good return");
            return endpoint.uuid;
          }
        });
      }else{
        continue;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

FINAL EDIT: awaiting the `getData` results made the trick as such:

```
static Future<String> getUuid(String id) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    for (String key in prefs.getKeys()){
      print("looking at $key");
      if (!key.contains("#")){
        var value = await getData(key);
        print("got this value: $value");
        Map<String, dynamic> endpointJson = jsonDecode(value);
        EndpointData endpoint = EndpointData.fromJson(endpointJson);
        print("endpoint.id: ${endpoint.id}");
        print("id: $id");
        if (endpoint.id == id){
          print("the good return");
          return endpoint.uuid;
        }
      }else{
        continue;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: jhust try to remove return null; i,side the if loop and put it after the for loop

Comment: I tried, but then I get the `The function has a return type of 'FutureOr<String>', but doesn't end with a return statement.` warning in the `getData` function. Just a warning, but I tested it and uuid still returned `null`. Will try again though.

Comment: Tested it and still null. Code used has been edited into the post.

Comment: if so ,  the getData(key).then((value) don't wait until it return the value to complete the iteration ( it tests the next value before the first is there )i prefer that you use await getData(key) so you're code will be oblige to wait untile the provide of the value to complete the execution

Comment: did you tried to use `var value = await getData(key);` do everything without `then()` and return `endpoint.uuid`?

Comment: awaiting the `getData` results worked. Could someone explain why? I thought `await` and `.then` where the same, both wait for Future to return something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code:

```
static Future<String> getUuid(String id) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    for (String key in prefs.getKeys()){
      print("looking at $key");
      if (!key.contains("#")){
        var value = await getData(key);
        print("got this value: $value");
        Map<String, dynamic> endpointJson = jsonDecode(value);
        EndpointData endpoint = EndpointData.fromJson(endpointJson);
        print("endpoint.id: ${endpoint.id}");
        print("id: $id");
        if (endpoint.id == id){
          print("the good return");
          return endpoint.uuid;
        }
      }else{
        continue;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```